# Why is there a red mark next to my ASP.NET files in the Solution Explorer?

Tags: asp.net, git, visual-studio

Every time I load my ASP.NET project I get these red marks next to my files. I do not know how to get rid of them. Can someone explain what they mean and what I should do about them?

[image: Picture of solution explorer]

Comment: I believe that means the file is being ignored by git. Check your `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181372%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

It says, it means these files are Excluded from version control

Represents an item that is not under Team Foundation version control because the user has explicitly excluded the item from version control.